# Can single-processor systems handle multi-level queue scheduling?

Tags: operating-system, scheduling

I know that in Asymmetric multiprocessing one processor can make all the scheduling decisions whilst the others execute user code only. But is it possible for a single-processor system to allow for multi-level queue scheduling? And why?

Answer (score 0):

Certainly a single processor system can use multi-level queue scheduling (MLQS).  The [MLQS algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multilevel_queue) is used to decide which process to run next when a processor becomes available.  The algorithm doesn't require that there be more than one processor in the system.  As a matter of fact, the algorithm is most efficient if there is only one processor.  In a multi-processor system the data structure would need some sort of locking to prevent it from being corrupted.